# Migrating symfony 3.4 to 4.4: Doctrine MappingException not a valid entity or mapped super class issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've migrated from **Symfony 3.4** to **4.4** and moved from using bundles to the **/src/** directory.
Doctrine throws an exception when I query an entity:

```php
$regions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Regions::class);
$regionInfo = $regions->findOneBy(array('region' => strtolower($regionSearch)));
```

> **Result**:
> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: "Class "App\Entity\Regions" is not a valid entity or mapped super class."

Here is the entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Regions")
 */

/**
 * Regions
 */
class Regions
{
    /** properties ... */
}
```

I'm wondering whether this is because it can't find the `orm.xml` which was in `bundle/Resources` ?
Also the `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM` appears unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your annotations should be set right above the class declaration:

```php
/**
 * Regions
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Regions")
 */
class Regions
```

With your current file, only the first docblock is read and as it is missing the `@ORM\Entity` annotation, Doctrine considers it isn't a valid entity class.